# What is the effect of temperature on the enthalpy of reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, enthalpy

In the study of reaction mechanisms, enthalpy of formation for intermediate compounds at various temperatures is studied. I understand the reason to do that.

How much (and what) effect can temperature have on the reaction enthalpy? Is it too different for different reactions, or is there some trend?

Answer (score 1):

The temperature trend of reaction enthalpy is determined by the difference of heat capacities of reagents and products, following the [Hess's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hess%27s_law). As total enthalpy change of heating reactants and cooling products back is nonzero.

$\Delta H_{\mathrm{r,}T_1}=\Delta H_{T_1 \rightarrow T_2} + \Delta H_{\mathrm{r,}T_2} + \Delta H_{T_2 \rightarrow T_1} $

$\Delta H_{\mathrm{r,}T_1}=
\int_{T=T_1}^{T_2}{[\sum_\mathrm{reagents}{(n_i \cdot C_{p,i})} \cdot \mathrm{d}T]} + 
\Delta H_{\mathrm{r,}T_2} + \int_{T=T_2}^{T_1}{[\sum_\mathrm{products}{(n_i \cdot C_{p,i})} \cdot \mathrm{d}T]}$